# AngularJS - select based on another one

Tags: angularjs, json, html-select

I've this JSON:

```
{
    "world": [{
        "name": {
            "en": "America"
        },
        "type": "continent",
        "children": [{
            "type": "state",
            "name": {
                "en": "Florida"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "state",
            "name": {
                "en": "Hawaii"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "name": {
            "en": "Europe"
        },
        "type": "continent",
        "children": [

        ]
    }]
}
```

I need to do two select. The first contain the selection of type "continent", the other one based on the first must be showed if the first one children's are > 0 and contain the selection of the states.

Comment: what about some js ? where is your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 <select name="client" ng-model="selectedRequest.continent" ng-options="c.name.en for c in clients.world" required></select>
 <select id="department" ng-model="selectedRequest.state" ng-options="d.name.en for d in  selectedRequest.continent.children"></select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/5z485cq1/1/)

EDIT

[Updated fiddle disabling select if children is empty](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/5z485cq1/6/)

Comment: your answer seems perfect.. how to hide the second select if there aren't children?

Comment: use ng-show and add your conditon, mark as answer if it has helped

Comment: ng-show="selectedRequest.continent.children > 0" doesn't work for me

Comment: @paolopolix did you check

Comment: if you check the console in your fiddle you'll look to some errors playing with it.. how can I solve them?